# Winjs for windows 10 UWP APP

Tags: winjs, windows-10

I've created an Windows 10 UWP project with JavaScript and use Winjs , but when I test some winjs ui controls ,that not run well .

eg1 :
SplitView , I follow http://try.buildwinjs.com/#splitview , and copy sample code (html,js,css) to UWP Project , and run it , but it can't split use top hamburger button

eg2 :
Appbar , the same follow http://try.buildwinjs.com/#appbar sample code , and run it ,but it throw Exception .

So ,Winjs already support windows 10 UWP or not ?

OS: windows 10 10130

Dev tool : Visual studio 2015 RC

Winjs : use nugget upgrade to version 4.0.1

Comment: I try remove winjs.js , and add base.js & ui.js , and run again , it run very well , what's difference winjs.js and base.js & ui.js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinJS version 4.x switch back to 2 files: base.js and ui.js.

WinJS version 3.x and 4.0 preview use winjs.js file .